# TFS update from 2017 Update 1 to 2017 Update 3.1 : error timeout database

Tags: tfs

At the office we run TFS 2017 Update 1. I try to update in TFS 2017 Update 3.1 and keep our database.

During the update, I select my configuration database to keep. *Readiness* step is OK. However during *Configure* step, more precisely during *Configuration Database* phase, it crash after ~15 minutes. The error is as follow :

> TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step 'Update Servicing Resources' for component FinishInstallUpdates during VsspFinishInstallUpdates: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.. For more information, see the configuration log.

The configuration log is really long, and at the end I can find that several requests timeout :

> [Error  @16:08:15.260] TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.
>   [Info   @16:08:15.261] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseOperationTimeoutException: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

After that, my database is corrupted. I load the backup and try again, same result. After loosing my day on it, maybe someone have an idea ?

Config :

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Database version 13.0.4001.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check whether the release manifest file is corrupted (Here is a [sample](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7qD1NqycgBlCJMARw5EPx--FHs) for your reference ):

  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools\Deploy\TfsServicingFiles\ReleaseManifest.xm`l
- If you have more than one Application Tier machine. Just restore
  `Tfs_Configuration` database and try below steps.

  1) Unconfigure TFS on all Application Tiers

  2) Wait 15 minutes

  3) Configure TFS 2017 Update3 .

  Reference [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108648/errors-upgrading-tfs-2017-update-1-to-update-2.html)
- If that still not work, just refer to below article to troubleshoot
  the issues (especially for the exception `TF246018` ) :

  [TFS 2017 – RESOLVING TF221122, TF246018, TF400307 AND TF400797
  ISSUES](https://dankovalkov.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/tfs-2017-resolving-tf221122-tf246018-tf400307-and-tf400797-issues/)

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer.

On dev community forums, someone advice me to upgrade the machine (add at least 2 cores for the VM). I think that can solve the problem. 

Unfortunately, I have to revert on Update 1 because others peoples at the office are using the TFS and can't wait any longer. If I have the opportunity to try again, I will test that.